# I am getting an error, cannot convert int* to int, but I can't figure out exactly what's causing it

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n; 
    cin >> n;

    int cows[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> cows[i];
    }

    int lowBound;
    int upBound;

    sort(cows, cows + n);

    int ans = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n-2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n-1; j++) {
            lowBound = lower_bound(cows + j + 1, cows + n, 2 * cows[j] - cows[i]);
            upBound = upper_bound(cows + j + 1, cows + n, cows[j] + 2*(cows[j] - cows[i]));
            if (lowBound == 9) {
                continue;
            }
            if (upBound == n) {
                upBound = n - 1;
            }
            ans += upBound - lowBound + 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error "invalid conversion from int* to int [-fpermissive]". However, I don't know what's causing it, I don't see where I am using a pointer where an int should go.

(I know that I am using things that are not recommended such as `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and using namespace std;, but please just help with the error before you tell me what else I should change unless it's directly related with the error)

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` return iterators, which in your case will be pointers. But you are trying to assign the return values from those functions to integer variables.

Comment: very likely, the compiler is telling you the exact line number where error happens: that can be useful...

Comment: your `using namespace std;` **is** related to the error. I had to check twice to be sure what is goiing on in your code

Comment: variable length arrays are not standard c++. Use a `vector` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should dereference your iterators:

```cpp
lowBound = *lower_bound(cows + j + 1, cows + n, 2 * cows[j] - cows[i]);
upBound = *upper_bound(cows + j + 1, cows + n, cows[j] + 2*(cows[j] - cows[i]));
```

as `lower_bound` returns an iterator and not a value.

Comment: Dereferencing without checking would be risky. Both functions could return the end of the array. In fact given the values of `j` in the loop, both functions are guaranteed to return `cows + n` at some point.